# Visual Studio nested macro/template classes debugging aid

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, macros

I was trying to build the Goptical package (https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/goptical ) in windows using Visual Studio 2019. It uses DPP library (https://code.ssji.net/hg/ ) which throws errors when building under Visual Studio. The Linux build with gcc goes smooth as expected, but I need this on windows with visual studio.

The errors come up from delegate classes which are nested template classes further wrapped inside using macros. Tried debugging but visual studio does not seem to pinpoint the exact location of the error, but instead point to last line which triggered the error.

Is there any mechanism by which we can see the macro definitions rolled back step by step? Or, an intermediate output that we could examine to debug this step by step? Posting the offending code and error details below:

```
1> delegate(578,1): error C2059: syntax error: ','
1> delegate(578): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'dpp::delegate_bind<base,R(void),3>' being compiled
```

Code:

```
#if DPP_DELEGATE_ARGC >= 2
  _DPP_DELEGATE(2)
  _DPP_DELEGATE_FUNC(2)
  _DPP_DELEGATE_MEMBER(2)
  _DPP_DELEGATE_MEMBER_THIS(2)
  _DPP_DELEGATE_BIND(1, 1, 1, _DPP_DELEGATE_BTDEFS(1, 0), _a0, a0);
  _DPP_DELEGATE_BIND(2, 1, 1, _DPP_DELEGATE_BTDEFS(1, 1), a0, _a0);
  _DPP_DELEGATE_BIND(3, 0, 2, _DPP_DELEGATE_BTDEFS(2, 0, 1), _a0, _a1);
#endif
```

Comment: Something I often find helpful with macro problems is to go into the project properties on the C/C++ -> Preprocessor page and set "Preprocess to file" to yes. Then I can examine the actual code the compiler is trying to consume.

Comment: the variadic macro is treated different between MSVC and gcc/clang, which always causes bugs in some preprocessor meta-programming library. but sadly, it seems that there is nothing that can make MSVC do the same as gcc/clang. so the author always should provide a different implementation in MSVC, just like what boost does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could set `Yes` in `Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocess to file`. Then, you could see the macro definitions in `XXX.i` file in the debug floder of the project.
[image]

[image]